# Como encontrar caracteres especiais que estão dentro de outras caracteres usando javascript

Tags: javascript, string

Tenho um valor string em formato de json '{"text": "Olha "eu" aqui"}' e que quero trocar essa aspa "eu" por que vai dar erro no código.
Eu tava pensando em usar o JSON.parse e fazer um loop nos itens, só que a função JSON não executa por causa do erro, por que não pode usar a mesma tipo de aspa do início e fim dentro da string a não ser para mencionar uma function ou var.

Acho que da para fazer isso usando replace para trocar as aspas que estão dentro das aspas.

Comment: De onde vem essa string?

Comment: Aonde ta sendo formatado esse Json, concordo com @brasofilo, o erro ta ai ?

Comment: esse é meu jeito de salvar as configurações, usando json em forma de string no localStorage em um aplicativo meu. Tenho medo do usuário colocar uma aspa e dar erro no código

Comment: A versão anterior do meu app não impedia ela, porém não dava erro, agora com a migração que vou fazer pode ser que nas configurações tenha essa aspa

Comment: Clássico [problema XY](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/como-lidar-com-o-problema-xy) :D

Answer (score 3):

[Como disse brasofilo nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12752/como-encontrar-caracteres-especiais-que-estao-dentro-de-outras-caracteres-usando#comment22107_12752), o ideal é impedir essa string errada de entrar no JSON em primeiro lugar. Tratar do problema depois do fato é bem mais difícil...

Se seu JSON tem **exatamente** esse formato, basta pegar tudo o que está dentro da string e fazer um replace:

```
var string = '{"text": "Olha "eu" aqui"}';
var prefixo = '{"text": "';
var sufixo = '"}';

var conteudo = string.substring(prefixo.length, string.length-sufixo.length);

var novaString = prefixo + conteudo.replace(/"/g, '\\"') + sufixo;
```

Se não tem, você está com problemas... Como interpretar a string abaixo?

```
{"text":"b","c":"d"}
```

1. Chave: `text`, valor: `b`; chave: `c`, valor `d`? ou:
2. Chave: `text`, valor: `b","c":"d`?

Ou seja: a única solução **correta** é tratar do problema antes da string ir parar no JSON. Se você tem por exemplo um arquivo legado em que - por um bug qualquer - o formato ficou errado desse jeito, você pode até usar um processo automatizado pra te ajudar a corrigir, mas tem que revisar à mão mesmo... Agora, se é um código existente que está gerando esse tipo de string, esse código está com bug e você deve corrigí-lo na fonte - e não aplicar um "band-aid"...

Comment: Vish =/ eu pensei que seria mais fácil e que com o exemplo que vc ia fazer dava pra eu adaptar. O json que eu uso tem muito mais coisas, tipo: '{"config": [{"text": "...", "type": "text"}, {"text": "...", "type": "text"}]}

E era pra remover as aspas de todos os "text" presente

Comment: @IagoBruno E não dá pra remover as aspas **antes** de colocar a string no JSON? Aliás, você não devia "montar" o JSON à mão: crie um objeto, depois use `JSON.stringify` nele. Se tiver alguma aspa nas strings ele "escapa" pra você.

Answer (score 1):

Se você que mudar todos os `"eu"` é fácil:

```
var string = '{"text": "Olha "eu" aqui"}';
var stringLimpa = string.replace('"eu"', 'eu');
```

Se você quer mudar todo o conteudo de `text` então pode testar isto:

```
var string = '{"text": "Olha "eu" aqui"}';
var conteudo = string.match(/{"text": "(.*)"}/)[1]; // criar um string com o conteudo
string = string.replace(conteudo, conteudo.replace(/"/g, '\'')); // subtituir o conteudo por novo conteudo com ' em vez de "
console.log(string); // {"text": "Olha 'eu' aqui"}  // só para confirmar

var json = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(json); // Object {text: "Olha 'eu' aqui"}
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/eH928/)

---

**Simplificando**, e colocando numa função:

```
function limpar(s) {
    var conteudo = s.match(/{"text": "(.*)"}/)[1];
    var conteudoLimpo = conteudo.replace(/"/g, '\'');
    s = s.replace(conteudo, conteudoLimpo);
    return JSON.parse(s);
};

var string = '{"text": "Olha "eu" aqui"}';
var objeto = limpar(string);
```

[**Exemplo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eH928/1/)